# How do I find who created or modified an Exchange 2010 contact in a public folder?

Tags: exchange-2010

Like the subject says, I'm looking to find out who made a change to a public folder contact in Exchange 2010.  I have a couple of use cases:

- Who added these contacts?
- Who deleted that contact?

I imagine they would have different places to look, but maybe not.  Some kind of audit log in Exchange?

It looks like [Public Folder Contacts - Exchange 2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/412955/public-folder-contacts-exchange-2010) has the answer for my second use case, bummer.

Comment: Same answer for "who added these contacts?", by the way.

Comment: Yuck.  Do you know what logs to turn on?  There are a lot of options in there...

Comment: In clarification, the "msexchangeis/9001 public/general" audit log doesn't seem to be logging changes (or I'm looking in the wrong place).  Someone who's done it before would know for sure.

Comment: may help: 1) http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrgenerallegacy/thread/0d5462a6-3e7b-49e3-b4f0-406a3b9e6708 2) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924044 3) http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/04/09/3409758.aspx  4) http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2009/12/04/3408943.aspx (great now I have Pitbull stuck in my head)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to Microsoft support said that, indeed, there isn't logging of this data.  There's a tool one can get from Microsoft to dump the entire Exchange DB and look at the owner of each object, but that won't help with deleted contacts.  It would show added contacts, but we would need to go look at the contact in question after it's changed.  Lame.

Comment: What is the name of the tool?  [ESEDBViewer](http://www.woanware.co.uk/?page_id=89) may help in this case.  Either way, no auditing logs = no "who did this action," unless I missed something?